# Why no code coloring on JSE?

Tags: feature-request

A lot of the answers on JSE contains code examples, usually PHP, HTML and CSS. But is there any reason why the color coding is not enabled? Other sites (like StackOverflow) will add nice colors to the code and make it easier to read.

Is this some kind of limitation on beta sites, or is it not considered necessary here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `prettify-full.en.js` file is not being imported on the JSE site. Not sure whether this is intentional or a mistake but I have to say it would be nice to have as it can sometimes make code readability much easier.

Maybe ask on Stackoverflow Meta